# Item Saved in Local Storage Reset on Page Refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a Context Provider; in there, I have a function to grab user details from another service (Cognito). Once I received the response, I set the user details in the state and in the local storage. Below is the piece of code that does the above.

```
    // get user details functionality
    const getUserDetails = async (accessToken) => {

        let postData        = { 'accessToken': accessToken };
        let result          = {};
        let code            = -1;
        let status          = ''
        let statusText      = ''
        let message         = ''

        await axios.post(Constants.URL_GET_USER_DETAILS, postData, {headers: headerData})
                        .then( data => {

                            code            = data.data.code;
                            status          = data.data.status;
                            statusText      = data.data.statusText;
                            message         = data.data.message;

                            //If successfully fetched user details
                            if (code === 200) {

                                let userDetails     = new CognitoUserDetails(message);

                                // save in the use state
                                setUserDetails(loggedUserDetails => userDetails)

                                // save in the local storage
                                setItemInLocalStorage( Constants.LOCAL_STORAGE_USER_DETAILS, userDetails);

                                result = message;
                                
                            } else {
                                
                            }

                        }).catch( error => {
                            
                        });

        return result;
        
    }
```

In the header component, I am setting the user details (basically the name of the logged-in user). As below;

```
    // use effect for user details
    useEffect( () => {

        let userDetails     = getUserDetailsFromStore();
        
        //Check if the user details are stored in state or local storage.
        if ( !Utilities.IsEmptyObject(userDetails) ) {
            
            // if they are, read from it
            console.log("details read from store");

        } else {

            //If it is not, send the request and get the user details
            let token       = getUserTokenFromStore();

            //If the token is there
            if ( !Utilities.IsEmptyObject(token) ) {
                
            } else {
                //else log out the user - as the token is not there, means the user has not logged in
            }

            userDetailsRequest(token.AccessToken)
                .then( data => {
                    
                    console.log("success::: user details request");
                });
        }

    }, [loggedUserDetails]);
```

In the above, if the state and the local storage do not have the user details stored, in the else part I sent a request to fetch the user details from the Cognito.

The "getUserDetailsFromStore()" function returns user details if it is set from the state or if not from the local storage.

```
    //Get user details from the state or from the local storage
    const getUserDetailsFromStore = () => {

        let token       = {};

        //If the user details are the state
        if ( !Utilities.IsEmptyObject(loggedUserDetails) ) {
            //Get it from the state
            token       = loggedUserDetails;

        } else {
            
            // else check if it is available in local storage
            let item        = getItemFromLocalStorage( Constants.LOCAL_STORAGE_USER_DETAILS );

            if ( Utilities.IsEmptyObject(item) ) {
                //Get it from local storage
                token       = item;

            } else {
                console.log("getUserDetailsFromStore:::: not in local storage");
            }
        }

        return token;
    }
```

Upon the successful login, user details are set in state and in local storage. But if I refresh the page, I am expecting to fetch the user details from the local storage but instead, it sends the request to Cognito to fetch the details again.

I am unsure where I am getting this wrong.

Comment: Can you show where you execute the function to clear localStorage?

Comment: I am not clearing the local storage in anywhere

Comment: It is supposed to be somewhere in the code since the localStorage won't clear itself even after the browser restart

Comment: There is only set local storage, in my code as you can see in the above I have provided. And do not clear in anywhere.

Comment: what is `setItemInLocalStorage`?

Comment: it sets item in local storage --> localStorage.setItem("userDetail", JSON.stringify(details));

Comment: You need to clarify that the local storage is clear or "userDetail" value is empty. Therefore you could know where to start debugging

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to the above question.

I got the if condition wrong in the following code.

```js
//Get user details from the state or from the local storage
    const getUserDetailsFromStore = () => {

        let token       = {};

        //If the user details are the state
        if ( !Utilities.IsEmptyObject(loggedUserDetails) ) {
            //Get it from the state
            token       = loggedUserDetails;

        } else {
            
            // else check if it is available in local storage
            let item        = getItemFromLocalStorage( Constants.LOCAL_STORAGE_USER_DETAILS );
            
            //ERROR WAS HERE, I SIMPLY FORGOT TO PUT "!" IN THE CONDITION, BECAUSE "IsEmptyObject" RETURNS TRUE IF IT IS EMPTY, HERE ITEM IS NOT EMPTY, HENCE FALSE
            if ( !Utilities.IsEmptyObject(item) ) {
                //Get it from local storage
                token       = item;

            } else {
                console.log("getUserDetailsFromStore:::: not in local storage");
            }
        }

        return token;
    }
```

The above code works fine.